# How to verify that a point is restorable without trying it out with FLASHBACK TABLE?

Tags: oracle

My goal is to mark restore points which is no longer valid for a set of tables  as "expired".

Whenever I say valid I imply that a query: `FLASHBACK TABLE :tables TO RESTORE POINT :point` would execute successfully.

How to do this?